# No pull possibility in DevOps plugin Visual studio

Tags: git, devops, pull

Does anyone know if the pull problem shown below can be solved by a setting? Or is it a bug? I can't pull anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and it was related to some old version of the VS Code. I solved it by updating the latest version following: https://devcoops.com/update-visual-studio-code-on-debian-based-distro/

Answer (score 0):

My git issues were also solved in a new version. I am now on Visual Studio 16.11.7.